# How to possible make a function that expresses the changes between absorbance of two samples, if only a few experiments are conducted?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

Each experiment is conducted by taking a spectra of non-radiated sample (sample is chemical compound in this instance) and determining the absorbance of it when radiated and non-radiated.

If I have a data about absorbance of sample when radiated vs. non radiated on almost each wavelength unit, and there are, for example, two such processes conducted, is there a way to compute a possible function that could express the changes in absorbance of the sample between radiated and non radiated states? As of now, few experiments have been conducted and it's been noted that for certain wavelength intervals there are differences in absorbance related to radiation, but is there a way to determine the function that could more precisely describe the change theoretically for all samples? (For example in program R)